# My first android app

Tags: android, date

I am building my first android app, and I am a bit confused with the Datepicker function. I am following the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html on the third step they are requesting to use a java file. I found the source code, but in which directory do I store this java file? is it in the res/values folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java source files are stored below the folder "src" according to your package name which you specified when creating the project.  Just follow the folders under src to the bottom one and put your Java files there.

Comment: Thanks, that is where I stored it. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The file `DatePicker.java` belongs in the `src` folder, because it's an actual Java source file.

The code sample that's given belongs inside the class `DatePicker`, since it defines private members for that class.  If that's something you don't really understand, you might want to spend some time learning Java before jumping right into Android development.  Take a look at [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) for the basics.  You could also check out [mobiletuts+'s Java for Android tutorials](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/) to get right into Android as you learn.